# merge list of data frames by different ids

Tags: r, merge

I have lists of variable length with dataframes. I want to merge the dfs in each list into a single df using a specified column name or index that varies by df. Here's an example with  3 dfs

```
my.list <- list(
data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10], c = 101:110),
data.frame(d = 6:15, e = letters[1:10], f = 1:10),
data.frame(l = 2:11, m = letters[11:20], o = 1:10))
```

and I want to merge by a specific column of each df mentioned in ids

```
ids <- c('a', 'f', 'l')
```

to get something that looks like

```
id  b   c   d   e   m   o
1   a   101 6   a   NA  NA
2   b   102 7   b   k   1
3   c   103 8   c   l   2
4   d   104 9   d   m   3
5   e   105 10  e   n   4
6   f   106 11  f   o   5
7   g   107 12  g   p   6
8   h   108 13  h   q   7
9   i   109 14  i   r   8
10  j   110 15  j   s   9
11  NA  NA  NA  NA  t   10
```

I've tried to do this with `merge` and/or `Reduce`, but failed to pass on the ids

Comment: Not clear about the `by` variables.  You have column  names different in each dataset.  Are you saying that alll the dataset should be merged by all the column sin 'ids'

Comment: yes, I edited the question a bit. Essentially I know the by variables (ids) but they differ among the dfs

Comment: Can one dataframe have both a and f columns?

Comment: yes. that wasn't clear from my question

Comment: and which column shall be used if there are for example a and f present in a dataframe?

Comment: @docendo discimus: the column mentioned in ids

Comment: There are some discussions about how to read `ids`. My understanding is that the first element of `ids` specifies the column in the first data.frame to merge on, the second element of `ids` belongs to the second data.frame in the list, and so forth. (Which means that `ids` must have exact the same number of elements as there are data.frames in the list). Is this the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can change the `names` unique to all the `list` elements by changing the column name that corresponds to 'ids' with 'id' and then do the `Reduce` with `merge`

```
lst <- Map(function(x, y) {names(x)[match(y, names(x))] <- 'id'; x}, my.list, ids)
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'id', all = TRUE), lst)
#   id    b   c  d    e    m  o
#1   1    a 101  6    a <NA> NA
#2   2    b 102  7    b    k  1
#3   3    c 103  8    c    l  2
#4   4    d 104  9    d    m  3
#5   5    e 105 10    e    n  4
#6   6    f 106 11    f    o  5
#7   7    g 107 12    g    p  6
#8   8    h 108 13    h    q  7
#9   9    i 109 14    i    r  8
#10 10    j 110 15    j    s  9
#11 11 <NA>  NA NA <NA>    t 10
```

Comment: dataframes can have more than 1 matching column names, see comments.

Comment: @zx8754  THe solution is based on the post `and I want to merge by a specific column of each df mentioned in ids`   If there are more than 1 matching names, the question and the example should be changed

Comment: Agree, I had similar solution in mind, but as we can see question is evolving unfortunately.

Comment: @zx8754  If there are more than matches, then 'ids' should be a `list` specific for each `list` element.  Not sure how that example turns out

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `data.table` answer with a similar approach as @akrun's answer.

However, instead of renaming the columns, we'll set them as keys. Then we can merge by keys, rather than by name. This preserves the column names.

```
library(data.table)

funky <- function(x) {
  setDT(my.list[[x]])
  setkeyv(my.list[[x]], ids[x])
  return(NULL)
}
```

So this function will be passed an index `x`. First, it will set the `data.frame` in the `xth` position of `my.list` to `data.table`. Then, it will set the key of this new `data.table` based on the column name specified at the same position in `ids`. Finally, since this is all done in place, return `NULL` to prevent useless printout.

Now apply the function to all of the objects in the list.

```
a <- lapply(seq_along(ids), funky)
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, 
                            y, 
                            by.x = key(x), 
                            by.y = key(y), 
                            all = TRUE), 
       my.list)
```

Unpacking the `Reduce`, we can specify the columns to merge by using `key(x)` and `key(y)`. This is the step that lets us avoid modifying the column names.

```
#      a  b   c  d  e  m  o
#  1:  1  a 101  6  a NA NA
#  2:  2  b 102  7  b  k  1
#  3:  3  c 103  8  c  l  2
#  4:  4  d 104  9  d  m  3
#  5:  5  e 105 10  e  n  4
#  6:  6  f 106 11  f  o  5
#  7:  7  g 107 12  g  p  6
#  8:  8  h 108 13  h  q  7
#  9:  9  i 109 14  i  r  8
# 10: 10  j 110 15  j  s  9
# 11: 11 NA  NA NA NA  t 10
```

Comment: I believe this is the only correct answer so far because it implements the request of the OP _I want to merge by a specific column of each df mentioned in ids_.

Answer (score 5):

An idea could be to convert the columns of interest into rownames and then merge on rownames, i.e.

```
l1 <- Map(function(x, y) {rownames(x) <- x[[y]]; x}, my.list, ids)
Reduce(function(x, y)merge(x, y, all = TRUE), lapply(l1, function(x) 
                                                 data.frame(x, id = rownames(x))))

#   id  a    b   c  d    e  f  l    m  o
#1   1  1    a 101  6    a  1 NA <NA> NA
#2  10 10    j 110 15    j 10 10    s  9
#3   2  2    b 102  7    b  2  2    k  1
#4   3  3    c 103  8    c  3  3    l  2
#5   4  4    d 104  9    d  4  4    m  3
#6   5  5    e 105 10    e  5  5    n  4
#7   6  6    f 106 11    f  6  6    o  5
#8   7  7    g 107 12    g  7  7    p  6
#9   8  8    h 108 13    h  8  8    q  7
#10  9  9    i 109 14    i  9  9    r  8
#11 11 NA <NA>  NA NA <NA> NA 11    t 10
```

Answer (score 3):

@Frank made a comment which made me think about a simple, straightforward loop:

```
# initialise result
result <- my.list[[1L]]
# add/merge remaining data.frames from list using the given column in ids to merge on
for (i in tail(seq_along(my.list), -1L)) {
  result <- merge(result, my.list[[i]], by.x = ids[1L], by.y = ids[i], all = TRUE)
}
result
```

> ```
>     a    b   c  d    e    m  o
> 1   1    a 101  6    a <NA> NA
> 2   2    b 102  7    b    k  1
> 3   3    c 103  8    c    l  2
> 4   4    d 104  9    d    m  3
> 5   5    e 105 10    e    n  4
> 6   6    f 106 11    f    o  5
> 7   7    g 107 12    g    p  6
> 8   8    h 108 13    h    q  7
> 9   9    i 109 14    i    r  8
> 10 10    j 110 15    j    s  9
> 11 11 <NA>  NA NA <NA>    t 10
> ```

This approach doesn't require to rename a single column of any of the data.frames in the list *before* the merges. However, to be consistent with the expected result of the OP, the `id` column may  be renamed afterwards:

```
tmp <- colnames(result)
colnames(result) <- replace(tmp, tmp == ids[1L], "id")
result
```

> ```
>    id    b   c  d    e    m  o
> 1   1    a 101  6    a <NA> NA
> 2   2    b 102  7    b    k  1
> 3   3    c 103  8    c    l  2
> 4   4    d 104  9    d    m  3
> 5   5    e 105 10    e    n  4
> 6   6    f 106 11    f    o  5
> 7   7    g 107 12    g    p  6
> 8   8    h 108 13    h    q  7
> 9   9    i 109 14    i    r  8
> 10 10    j 110 15    j    s  9
> 11 11 <NA>  NA NA <NA>    t 10
> ```

---

Note the OP has pointed out several times that the  `ids` vector contains the name of the column to be merged for *each* of the data.frames:

> [*I want to merge by a specific column of each df mentioned in ids*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45237530/3817004), and
>   [*Essentially I know the by variables (ids) but they differ among the dfs*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237530/merge-list-of-data-frames-by-different-ids/45239904#comment77441082_45237530)

Therefore, I'm afraid the answers using `match()` might be wrong.

Answer (score -2):

to merge something i can advice you to use the command sqldf from the package sqldf and you can do it like this:

```
A = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10], c = 101:110)
B = data.frame(d = 6:15, e = letters[1:10], f = 1:10)
C = data.frame(l = 2:11, m = letters[11:20], o = 1:10)
joined_df <- sqldf('select A.*,B.*,C.* from A left join B on A.a=B.f left join C on A.a=C.l')
```

Comment: Imagine list of 20 dataframes... how would your code look like.

Comment: So what about using the by.x and by.y arguments of merge function ?